# How to sync remote git repository with my own repo (not in github, not able to fork)?

Tags: git

I am trying to work out the an online lab(6.824), which is hosted in MIT's own git server instead of github. But I want to do some version control myself by uploading the codes to my github repo (a private one, currently empty).

I would like to

1. Be able to pull/fetch further commits from the lab and sync to my repo in github.
2. Only maintain one copy of code instead of 2 repositories.

Is there any simple way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Add both repos as remotes. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: @Julian's answer. Plus any new branches you make, give them unique names not present on the original repo. This is _not_ strictly necessary, it will just make things less confusing for you is all.

Comment: Not sure I understand #2, so here's my best shot at trying to answer it: You'll have at least 2 repos: MIT and GitHub - if the MIT repo is reachable from GitHub's Import page. If MIT's repo isn't reachable from GitHub, you'll need a local repo pointing to two remotes - adding up to 3 repos in total.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I just added my repo as a remote and now I can sync with it. @Julian If you'd like to repost an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Done! I also prefer answered questions :)

Comment: @Julian Accepted. Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add both repos as remotes. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

E.g.
To add a remote

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/user/myrepo.git
```

To list all configured remotes

```
git remote -v
```